# Making Command 1-time-executable

Tags: mvvm, prism, delegatecommand, canexecute

what is best practice to make a `DelegateCommand` from `Prism` framework in `MVVM` only one time executable in order to prevent click-spamming the button which may result in application crashes.
many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RelayCommand change canExecute automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927967/relaycommand-change-canexecute-automatic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I normally do:

- You should have a property for what you are deleting. Use CanExecute
- in your delegate command, watch the property if it is null? Use
- ObserveProperty in your DelegateCommand and set it to What you are
- deleting. In your DeleteCommandExecute set the property to null after deleting.

here is an example

```
    private Class object;
    public Class Object
    {
        get { return object; }
        set { SetProperty(ref object, value); }
    }
    private DelegateCommand _delete;
    public DelegateCommand Delete =>
        _delete ?? (_delete = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteDelete, CanExecuteDelete)).ObservesProperty(()=> Object);

    void ExecuteDelete()
    {
        MyServices.Delete(Object);
        Object = null;
    }

    bool CanExecuteDelete()
    {
        return Object != null;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say like CanExecuteDelete = false after void ExecuteDelete() and instead of ObservesProperty using ObservesCanExecute(()=>CanExecuteDelete)? Ty for your answer!

Comment: if you use CanExecuteDelete= false then you will not be able to click the command. The answer provided will check the canExecuteMethod only if the object raised a notification. That is why i set the object to null in the ExecuteCommand which will raise a notification which will cause the command to check the CanExecute.